# How to store multiple rows returned from SQL command into a nvarchar variable?

Tags: java, sql, spring, azure

I need to simulate a procedure, that return a OUT parameter of type nvarchar(max). The value of this parameter is a string concatenation of multiple rows of user (containing multiple column like id, name, age, etc).

The problem is that all I see are suggestion to store the result of a SELECT command on a signe column for multiple rows. I need to do the SELECT on a multitude of row, but on all of their column value (most likely using SELECT *).

I created a table type named User.

```
CREATE TYPE user AS TABLE
(   Id int,
    No_user int,
    Name nvarchar(30),
    // etc.
    )
```

I created the procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE some_procedure(
    @No_user int,
    @List_User nvarchar(max) OUTPUT,
    )

    AS
```

Then inside the procedure, I'm declaring a variable of type user and inserting values:

```
DECLARE @userList user
INSERT INTO @userList Values (1,1,"John",..), (2,2,"Jane",..)
```

Then I created the command, used Stuff to collect the result into a nvarchar format:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @tmpList varchar(MAX)
SELECT @sqlCommand = STUFF ((SELECT ',*' FROM @userList FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '')
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@tmpList varchar(max) output', @tmpList output
```

Then used a SELECT to store @tmpList into the @List_User:

```
SELECT @List_User = @tmpList
```

I'm testing the procedure, but I'm getting the following errors:

Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

or

Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a table and inserted values as mentioned below:

```
CREATE  TABLE Users 
(   Id int,
    No_user int,
    Name nvarchar(30),
    
)
INSERT INTO Users Values (1,1,N'John'), (2,2,N'Jane')
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I created stored procedure as mentioned below:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE some_procedure(
    @No_user int,
    @List_User nvarchar(max) OUTPUT
    )

    AS
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I created the sql command to store multiple rows into one string which is the type of nvarchar with below code

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @tmpList varchar(MAX)
SELECT @sqlCommand = STUFF ((SELECT '*' FROM Users FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '')
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@tmpList varchar(max) output', @tmpList output
```

I got the same error as you mentioned above
Image for reference:

[image]

I changed the data type of @sqlcommand from "varchar" to "nvarchar" as mentioned below

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX)
```

It run successfully without any error.
Image for reference:

[image]

It worked for me kindly try from your end.